# Mongodb delay to provide data by vercel API

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query, vercel

I create simple CRUD project with Reactjs. For server side, I use express and vercel for deploy the server codes. I use Mongodb for database. In mongodb I create a database and create 2 collection for relavent usage. But after deploy the code to vercel, Mongodb dose not provide data suddenly. Means, the vercel api working good. Suddenly, 1 hour or 30 minutes later if I go to the API, then the mongodb maybe never hit. After some reload I getting data from mongodb. Same issue again after 5 minutes or 10 minutes later.

here is my server side codes:

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())


const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@ass-11.8xhsqle.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=AtlasApp`;

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    serverApi: {
        version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
        strict: true,
        deprecationErrors: true,
    }
});

// JWT token verify 
const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: true, message: 'unauthorized access' });
    }
    const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).send({ error: true, message: 'unauthorized access' })
        }
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
    })
}


async function run() {
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
        await client.connect();
        const servicesCollection = client.db('carService').collection('services');
        const bookingCollection = client.db('carService').collection('booking');

        // jwt
        app.post('/jwt', (req, res) => {
            const user = req.body;
            console.log(user);
            const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });
            console.log(token);
            res.send({ token });
        })

        app.get('/services', async (req, res) => {
            const options = {
                sort: {
                    service_id: 1
                }
            }
            const cursor = servicesCollection.find({}, options);
            const result = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(result);
        })
        // load a specific data for booking page
        app.get('/services/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) }

            const options = {
                // Include only the `title` and `imdb` fields in the returned document
                projection: { title: 1, price: 1, service_id: 1, img: 1 },
            };

            const result = await servicesCollection.findOne(query, options);
            res.send(result);
        })
        // user all booking show page 
        // bookings routes
        app.get('/userOrder', verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
            const decoded = req.decoded;

            if (decoded.email !== req.query.email) {
                return res.status(403).send({ error: 1, message: 'forbidden access' })
            }

            let query = {};
            if (req.query?.email) {
                query = { email: req.query.email }
            }
            const result = await bookingCollection.find(query).toArray();
            res.send(result);
        })

        app.post('/addService/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const booking = req.body;
            console.log(booking);
            const result = await bookingCollection.insertOne(booking);
            res.send(result);
        });

        app.patch('/userOrder/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const filter = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
            const updatedBooking = req.body;
            const updateDoc = {
                $set: {
                    status: updatedBooking.status
                },
            };
            const result = await bookingCollection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc);
            res.send(result);
        })

        app.delete('/userOrder/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) }
            const result = await bookingCollection.deleteOne(query);
            res.send(result);
        })
        // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
        await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
    } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        // await client.close();
    }
}
run().catch(console.dir);



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Car repair is running!');
})

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`${port} listening this site!`);
})
```

Main issue is why it is taking time or delay to provide data? I check everything is ok but I did not find out solution.
Here is my vercel deploy api link: https://car-solution.vercel.app/services
If you see **Cannot GET /services** then reload few times. Then it will showing data from mongodb. this is my problem. Why data not showing first time? Why I need to reload?
Kindly help me!!

Comment: I tried several times, having no delays or other issues...  Seems fine

Comment: Thanks for your try, Actually I fixed this problem. That's why you did not face any delay or problem.